# Fast CSV reader

Tags: c#

I am working on a project, which actually loads data from a CSV file, processes it and then save it on the disk. For fast reading of CSV data, I am using Lumenworks CSV reader http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader. This works fine till a limit but when I have CSV with a size of 1GB or more, it takes time. Is there any other way for faster CSV reading?

Comment: Where does the CSV come from? Is it possible to get it in a more efficient form?

Comment: CSV is trivial... I can't imagine a scenario where the CPU usage would be noticeable over the IO time.  If you could provide some info/code on what you're actually doing it would be useful.

Comment: 1GB of data does indeed take time. That sounds like an IO limit...

Comment: Yeah, chances are that you've exceeded the capability of your machine, not the library. Oops.

Comment: Grab a faster hard drive

Comment: As others said: probably an IO limitation. But also make sure you are processing line by line as you read, instead of first reading the entire file in memory, followed by processing from memory. If not, you may run into memory management issues, including swapping memory out to disk.

Comment: While not speeding up the process, you could give the perception of faster loading if you can display some output even before you are completely finished loading the file.

Comment: @Kris, I am not keeping full csv in memory and I am also processing row by row and dumping the processed data on disk after I have reached some limit (for ex: I will only write data on disk once I have 10000 rows of data in memory) to reduce the I/O operations.

Comment: Consider not buffering your output yourself. Just use a normal FileStream, optionally increasing its buffer to something more than 4KB. But you really don't need a lot! Windows will buffer, cluster and otherwise optimize the disk IO for you anyway. Your "optimization" may in fact be "overhead", if you're not very careful.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of info provided... so on the assumption that this is an IO limitation your options are:

1. Get Faster Storage [e.g. SSD, RAID].
2. Try compression -    sometimes the time spent in compression [e.g Zip] saves multiples in IO.
3. Try threading - particularly useful if doing computationally hard calculations - but probably a bad fit in this scenario.
4. Change the problem - do you need to read/write a 1GB file?  Maybe you can change the data format [156 is a lot smaller than "156,", maybe you only need to deal with smaller blocks, maybe the time taken honestly doesn't matter etc.

Any others?

Hmm, you could try caching the output, I've experimented with MemoryMappedFiles & RAM Drives... you could do it with some simple threading... while this does potentially return sooner, it has huge risks and complexities